# jetty version error when running mvn install

Tags: maven, jetty, pom.xml

I have the below in my POM file:

```
<properties>

    <main.basedir>${project.basedir}/..</main.basedir>

    <jettyVersion>9.2.3.v20140905</jettyVersion>

    <jersey.version>2.15</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

When I run mvn install getting this error with regards to versioning:

```
The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.glassfish.jersey.container:jersey-container-servlet:jar:9.2.3.v20140905
```

Comment: You have used the `jettyVersion` property (instead of  `jersey.version`) with the **jersey**-container-servlet dependency.

Answer (score 2):

Correctly pointed by @Steve C in the comments, you seem to be using incorrect property name as the value of the `version` for jersey-container-servlet. The version as specified in the error *jersey-container-servlet: jar:9.2.3.v20140905* doesn't exist [as seen here](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.glassfish.jersey.containers%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jersey-container-servlet%22). You can make sure the version used is either:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.15</version>
</dependency>
```

or use your defined property `jersey.version` as:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
```